# Vectorized Counting in 2D array python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to build a function that counts up zeros in a list until nonzero entry appears, and start counting from 0 again. For example,

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

In this case, my desired output will be

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I tried making this with two for-loops, but it is very slow on a very large data set. I was hoping I could find a way to vectorize this operation so that the time is O(n) instead of O(n^2). Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Vectorization doesn't really affect the runtime complexity. And a simple for-loop should be O(n) in the size of the array.

Comment: if the operation goes `for i in range(n): for j in range(m):` then it is O(n^2), isn't it?

Comment: Vectorization only improves the constant factor, not the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: So it has to be O(n^2) no matter what?

Comment: @anyhoon it depends on what **`n` is**. Typically, we speak in terms of the total size of the array. So, in that case, **no** it is O(n). if `n` is *the length of the first dimension* then yes, that algorithm would be O(n^2), but typically, you are interested in the big-oh complexity in terms of the *total size of the array*.

Comment: @anyhoon think of it this way. We have a simple algorithm, it iterates over an MxM array and adds 1 to each element. Say we have a 5x5 array, so the total size, N = 25. How many operations do we perform? 25. Now, for a 6x6 array, total size = 36. How many operations do we perform? 36. Increasing the *total size* from 25 to 36 (+11) made us do +11 more operations - linear. However, if we speak in terms of the dimension M,  then obviously, it scales quadratically. So, you have to be precise.

Comment: Honestly, this algorithm is so simple, I think you could easily implement it in Cython, or maybe even use `numba` to good effect.

Comment: @anyhoon but seriously, check out `numba`, I'm seeing 200+ times speed up with a jit version versus normal, both the exact-same naive implementation. These are the situations where `numba` was *designed to shine*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this, which is vectorized and has no `for` loops:

```
def moving_count(a, value, axis=0):
    """Return sequential counts of a given value along an axis"""
    if np.all(a == value):
        # Fill the output with counts along the desired axis
        return np.rollaxis(np.arange(1, a.size + 1).reshape(a.shape), axis)

    # Allocate output with a cumulative count of value along flattened axis
    output = np.cumsum(np.rollaxis(a, axis) == value)

    # Find locations of breakpoints
    breakpoints = (np.roll(output, 1) - output) == 0

    # Since breakpoints is boolean, argmax returns the location of the first breakpoint
    threshold = np.argmax(breakpoints)

    # Repeat the cumulative value along labels and subtract to reset the count at each breakpoint
    output[threshold:] -= output[breakpoints][np.cumsum(breakpoints) - 1][threshold:]

    # Reshape and return axis to match input array
    return np.rollaxis(output.reshape(a.shape), axis)
```

Applied to your problem:

```
In[3]: a = np.array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  2],
                     [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1],
                     [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
                     [ 0,  0, 10,  2,  2],
                     [ 2,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
In[4]: moving_count(a, 0, 1)
Out[4]: 

array([[1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might make it a little faster:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  2],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1],
              [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0, 10,  2,  2],
              [ 2,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

b = (a == 0)
c = np.zeros_like(a)
c[0, :] += b[0, :]
for i in range(1, c.shape[1]):
    c[i, :] = b[i, :] * (1 + c[i-1, :])
```

Array 'c' gives the desired result.

Or optimizing a little further...

```
a = ...
b = (a == 0) * 1
for i in range(1, b.shape[1]):
    b[i, :] *= (1 + b[i-1, :])
```

Now 'b' is your result, and you've got one array less to deal with.

You'll notice that this algorithm still has the same time complexity as the 'two for loop' solution, but now one of those loops is being internalized by numpy, so I would expect a speedup on a large array.